# Purchasing and resetting neuromods

Tags: prey

In Prey you can find Neuromods to purchase upgrades in a skill tree.

There are 3 categories: Scientist, Engineer and Security. All of these have a lot of perks and require multiple neuromods to purchase skills.

I have 2 questions about this ability system:

1. Are there enough neuromods in the game to purchase all the skills available?
2. Can I reset my neuromods (early) somehow if I accidentally purchased something wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. No. You will unlock 3 more categories later, you can't find enough neuromods to get all skills. You will be able to craft neuromods later though.
2. Not as far as I know. I have not found any way to reset your skills.

Comment: Small note: according to the plot removing the neuromod results in loss of memory. But it is impossible to erase player memory, so removing neuromods is impossible in terms of gameplay mechanics.

Comment: While it's good to save up a few and plan your trek down the tree, don't be like me and horde them so that you end the game with 22 sitting in your inventory!